# EXCEL: how to enter text verbatim

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I am using MS Excel. How do I enter text into a box so that it shows up verbatim the way I entered.

E.g.
If I enter 4-2, I want it show up as 4-2 and not as 2-Apr automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to prepend an **apostrophe/single quote** (**'**) to the string you're entering.
So, in your example, type:

```
'4-2
```

Answer (score 0):

Start entering the text with a single quote ('): '4-2